# What Python lib supports SVG rendering attr vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"?

Tags: python, svg, imagemagick, render, cairo

I've faced the lack of ability to render SVG files applying SVG 1.2 attribute `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` using Python. I've tested lots of libs, but almost all of them supports only SVG 1.1 and a harvest of SVG 1.2 features. This attribute is supported well by all the modern web browsers and I used this feature to render SVG via webkit.

Does anyone know the modern Python lib, which already does supports `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` ?

I've unsuccessfully tried next:

```py
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
drawing = svg2rlg("test.svg")
pil_img = renderPM.drawToPIL(drawing)
```

```py
import cairosvg

png_data = cairosvg.svg2png(
    bytestring=str(svg_data).encode(),
    output_width=scaled(svg_width),
    output_height=scaled(svg_height),
)

pil_img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(png_data))
```

```bash
# ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25
convert test.svg test.png

# non-scaling-stroke is taken into account on Xubuntu 22.04 desktop
# and is ignored on nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04
# docker image (need here for deploy)
```

```bash
inkscape -o test.png test.svg

# works well on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop
```

Comment: Random idea that didn't lead anywhere: Check in which Debian packages this string appears. Sadly, https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=non-scaling-stroke&literal=1 didn't end up with anything that sounded too helpful.